# Vue+ laravel Adaptation of the size of the modal window to the size of the screen

Tags: css, vue.js, mobile, vue-component

I have modal window.

```
<transition name="modal" @close="showModal = false">
        <div class="modal-mask" style="  width: 90% !important;">
            <div class="modal-wrapper">
                <div class="modal-container">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <slot name="header">
                            Введите сообщение для
                        </slot>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <slot name="body">
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="45" v-model="MessageText" name="MessageText"</textarea>                            
                        </slot>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>
```

On small screens (phones), the screen goes beyond the screen. How to make it adaptive to fit the screen?

Upd [image]

Answer (score 0):

for making modal size you can use

```
class="modal-dialog modal-lg"
```

hope that will work and make sure width is removed.